# Maven dependency for Spark's StreamingQuery

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I have a compile-time error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'spark'

For the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
```

I use InteliJ.

pom.xml:

```
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Edit:**

I've noticed that Maven complains about the spark-sql dependency:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct maven dependency?

Comment: @Joe no, I'm not.

Comment: try this `import org.apache.spark.*;` and see if it builds

Comment: Is your Scala version 2.11.something?

Comment: @Palcente no, I still have the same error.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I use Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the interface org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery exists in spark-sql_2.11:2.4.0 with the source code available here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQuery.scala

I assume that the compilation error is related to the import in the source code, and not to some type (you haven't attached the source code of the file that has a failure, so I can only speculate here)

So, in terms of resolution:

1. try running `mvn clean compile` **from command line** without intelliJ. If it succeeds - check intelliJ integration (maybe re-import will fix the issue).
2. If it doesn't - check the `pom.xml` maybe you've updated a `<dependencyManagement>` section by mistake.
3. Remove the jars of spark from local maven repository and retry, sometimes its possible that the jar will get downloaded corrupted

**Update 1**
Since now we know that `mvn clean compile` from the command line runs successfully,
this must be an issue of opening project in intelliJ.

So I suggest to do the following:

1. Close the current project: File --> Close Project
2. File --> Open...  Now find the project folder and (this is important) pick `pom.xml`. IntelliJ will ask whether you want to delete the previously found project files - respond "yes" and it will re-build an internal dependencies data structures.
   Then Try to run the program and update whether the issue exists.

Comment: So have you tried the 1 item from the command line (without intelliJ)? What do you see?

Comment: Isn't Maven installed if I have Maven inside my InteliJ and also my Eclipse?

Comment: You have some version of maven bundled inside intelliJ... True. I don't know about eclipse. I'm talking about the attempt to run `mvn clean install` bypassing the intelliJ...

Comment: I've run "mvn clean compile". It hasn't helped.

Comment: perhaps you can add MVN_HOME variable to point to the built-in Maven directory in IntelliJ

Comment: @LongVu I've already managed to install Maven. "mvn clean compile" runs successfully but it doesn't solve the dependency issue.

Comment: @Alon, Please see the update on my answer, now, when you've stated than `mvn clean compile` runs successfully. Please update on the result. I'm monitoring this question :)

Answer (score 1):

"Spark Framework" at http://sparkjava.com/ has nothing to do with [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org). Remove the `com.sparkjava` dependency (assuming it's not needed elsewhere in your project) and replace it with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```