# Unable to run JUnit tests inside a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have a 3-year old Maven project that was working fine in IntelliJ IDEA 3 years ago. I'm trying to return to the project now, but I can't get JUnit tests to run anymore. There's nothing fancy with the tests themselves, it's really basic `@Test` and `assertTrue` stuff. I suspect the issue lies with my `pom.xml` file.

If I try to run tests with the original pom.xml file from 3 years ago, I get an error "No tests found". I tried to update my dependencies, and after updating I get a different error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Optional org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getTestInstanceLifecycle()'`. It appears to be some kind of internal error from JUnit. I've spent 1 hour googling, and I've randomly tried different ways of setting up the dependencies, but nothing so far works.

How should a `pom.xml` file look in order to allow basic JUnit tests to be run in a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 Community Edition?

[Here](https://github.com/baobabKoodaa/baopass/blob/07bfc995b13f40d9b1c87e3510b39e4d69110a6c/pom.xml) is the pom.xml file from 3 years ago.

Comment: Please see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea

Comment: @CrazyCoder If you are implying that I should try to structure my pom.xml according to the "Additional Maven dependencies" in your link, yeah, I tried that earlier and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: No, you need to use the up to date versions of the dependencies, not the obsolete pre-release (milestone) versions as you are using now. So updating `5.0.0-M3` to `5.6.0` will fix the issue. [Proof of working](https://i.imgur.com/FZeGPGt.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried the 5.6.0 version specifically and it did not fix the issue. I can see in your image that you managed to get it running. Could you please paste the entire pom.xml file for me?

Comment: Here you are: https://pastebin.com/raw/hTETUE5v. Make sure to reimport the project so that IntelliJ IDEA updates the dependencies.

Comment: I did as you said, and still couldn't get it to work. Then I decided to clone the project again, replace the pom on the clone, and import the clone into IntelliJ IDEA. And it worked! In other words, something in my `.idea` project configuration must have caused the issue, and a fresh project configuration (with the updated dependencies) solved it.

Comment: Most likely, you didn't refresh the project so IDE was still using the old dependencies.

Comment: Are those unit tests JUnit 4 based?

Answer (score 1):

All-in-all you should create a dependency on `junit-jupiter-engine` and not on the api (the engine will bring the api) and upgrade a version of surefire plugin that runs the tests:

```
    <dependencies>

        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ...
     <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Requires at least 2.22.0 otherwise junit 5 doesn't work-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
          ...
         </plugins>
   </build>
```

You can find the working example of minimal setup (that is pretty close to you fairly basic pom.xml) [in this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/junit5/junit-5-maven-examples/)

Comment: I tried this now, but I'm still getting the same error. Here is the pom.xml after I edited it according to your answer: https://pastebin.com/7U40pnm9

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Optional org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getTestInstanceLifecycle()'

Comment: I'v e downloaded the project from github, substituted the original pom.xml with the one that you've provided in the first comment and tried to run mvn clean test. It started to execute EntropyTest so the tests are recognized and run. I'm using maven 3.6.1 and jdk 12. Can you show the output of the whole maven build (mvn clean test command at least)?

Comment: Here is as much of the output as IntelliJ is giving me: https://pastebin.com/GsEqyDMr

Comment: I can confirm now that the build has run successfully on my machine. I meant not only the error but the whole output of the command `mvn clean test` run from the command line without intelliJ at all.

Comment: I've realized now that you're trying to run the project in intellij. For now, don't do this yet. Instead make sure that you have a pom.xml that runs with your locally installed maven correctly. Then reimport the whole project (like I've suggested here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135830/maven-dependency-for-sparks-streamingquery/60135918#60135918)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I eventually got it working by creating a new IntelliJ project (see comments on OP for more info).

Comment: yeah, thats pretty much the same that I've offered to do in the last comment. Anyway, glad you've got it resolved. Good luck